# How to copy all board task headers within column to clipboard in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

I want to copy a single column of Trello cards to my clipboard (just the card titles).

If, for example, I have the following three columns:

```
TODO       DOING      DONE

Task3      Task2      Task1

Task4
```

and I want to copy only the "TODO" column, so the output will be:

```
Task3
Task4
```

Is this possible with some shortcut/action in Trello?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Contractor app recommended by @xtoq is no longer available. If you are comfortable with using the browser console, the following JavaScript snippet from [this blog post](http://www.secretgeek.net/trello_ws) does the job:

```
var s = [];
s.push("# " + jQuery(".board-header").children()[0].innerText);
jQuery(".list:has(.list-header-name)").each(function() {
    s.push("\n## " + jQuery(this).find(".list-header-name")[0].value + "\n");
    jQuery(this).find(".list-card-title").each(function() {
        s.push("* " + this.innerText);
    });
});
copy(s.join("\n"));
```

(Tested with Chrome Developer Tools console.)

Comment: would like to share another script to this approach in browsers console: `Array.from(document.querySelector('.js-list:nth-of-type(13)').querySelectorAll('.list-card-title')).map((item) => {console.log(item.innerText)})`
where 13 here is the number of your desired column.
got quite good result for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it's not natively possible. If you're comfortable with third-party solutions, there's one called Contractor that takes your lists and translates them to plain text for easy copy/pasting. It sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

http://contractor.launchpadlab.com

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one quick method, although it also copies any dates and checklist counts also, which is not always what you want. Here's the instructions for Google Chrome, although Firefox and Safari will have similar functions, just may not appear exactly the same:

1. Right click the heading of a column that you'd like to copy
2. Click "Inspect"
3. In the "Styles" box on the right, scroll down until you see `#board` and uncheck the `-webkit-user-select` and `user-select` options. It is these that prevents you from selecting the text as normal.

   [image]
4. Back on the Trello screen, very carefully swipe your mouse from the top left of the column to the bottom right, selecting as much text as you can. Sometimes this takes a bit of practice to start and stop dragging in the correct places to encompass the text. Especially since the card labels don't always appear to be getting selected, even if they are.
5. Copy to clipboard! Done.

(You may have to manually remove extra characters such as due dates and checklist counts etc.)

Hope that helps!